# how to by pass following error in Firefox extension "server does not support RFC 5746"

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a FireFox extension 
when I do xhr to the Secure server , particularly POST a data
it gives a status 500, and following mesage:

> onsip.highrisehq.com : server does not
>   support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555

How can I by pass by It? I assume that this is because of the Server misconfiguration, but I can't wait till someone from 37 signal will fix it. thanks for your help

Comment: Same problem, in my case, with a standalone Xulrunner application, when trying to access mail.yahoo.com.

Comment: concerning the issue , it turned out to be just warning if you inspect the requests, they should go just fine

Comment: Yes, the message here shows as a info message, not an error. Still, the page is not loaded.

Comment: Try to see the requests i/o , in my case I could see it with a help of firefox - "httpfox" addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - "see [**CVE-2009-3555**](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555)". Basically it's a server side vulnerability which might allow to compromise a TLS/SSL session.

I'm not sure there's anything you can do on the client side to resolve this, until 37signals update their servers.

Comment: You're right. Due to the vuln, even the assumption "when I do xhr to the **secure** server" doesn't hold. Doing xhr, sure, but with whom?

Comment: Maybe is a server's problem. But if the error occurs only in Firefox, so should exist a solution from the client side (if other clients works fine), I think.. Don't you?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a hack, but another option (instead of the XHR request) is a "hidden" (1px by 1px) IFRAME.  It's not pretty, but I've used it in situations where I had (different) problems with the XHR route (and there might even be a way to hide it entirely, but the 1px/1px works for me so I've never bothered to try anything else).

Just change the frame's src attribute to "make a request", then view it's document to read the "response".

Comment: I'm taking care of another issue now, but thanks for the hint, I'll test it latter. By the way, I'll award you the bount, as it will just now.